# Sync BreezeJS managers || Broadcast BreezeJS changes

Tags: javascript, breeze

When BreezeJS persists changes, it passes the changes to a method like this in the WebAPI controller:

```
    [HttpPost]
    public SaveResult SaveChanges(JObject saveBundle) {
        SaveResult result = _contextProvider.SaveChanges(saveBundle);
        return result;
    }
```

Does there exist a method which could handle a transformed version of the "result" variable above from the server, such that it could be used to synchronize other EntityManagers?

Much like how Firebase, CouchDB, Derby or a handful of others have accomplished, is there a way to bring all other managers up to speed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there is no automatic synchronization of Breeze client EntityManagers with the results of successful saves on the server nor any form of data replication between database and clients. You could ask for such thing in [our UserVoice](https://breezejs.uservoice.com/forums/173093-breeze-feature-suggestions).