# BreezeJS method needed to apply a saveResult to a seperate sandbox manager

Tags: entity-framework, breeze, optimistic-concurrency

I am currently writing a mobile application that requires offline capability.

I have 2 breeze contexts a master and a sandbox. Both share the same model and metadata (generated from EF6 using [BreezeController]).

A single sandbox is sufficient for now however multiple sandboxes may be required if the number of required workflows increases.

The sandbox context is a complete clone of the master context and all workflows where data can be changed use the sandbox context. When a user saves the sandbox this exports the changed state entities and imports into to the master context.

As the user continues their journey the master context polls the server for a connection (and will often fail). If a connection is found then the master context will save it's data back to the server. Therefore persisting the master state to the persistent store but not any changed data in the sandbox caused by the users current workflow.

The point where I need help is when this save has happened I need to update the id mappings on the sandbox. (e.g. the user is currently in workflow adding an order to a new customer in the sandbox customerId:-2. The master context in the background manages to save the customer updating -2 to [34]. But the sandbox retains the customer with id:-2.)

I was hoping someone might be able to suggest the best way to do this. I have considered:

**First:**

Subscribing to the changed entities in the master context and updating the sandbox when the entity id changes. (not very clean)

```
datacontext.manager.entityChanged.subscribe(function (changeArgs){
  /*look for the changes to the id and import the relevant entities*/
})
```

**Second:**

Writing a custom data service adapter to deal with this. Though this appears to be overkill. But will happily take this on if the best option.

**Third (and preferable if possible)**

On the master context changes succeeded event take the saveResult and apply to the sandbox context.

```
function(){
    return manager.saveChanges()
       .then(saveSucceeded)
       .fail(saveFailed)

    function saveSucceeded(saveResult) {
        /* Apply the saveResult to the sandbox */
    }
}
```

Any suggestions of the best way to approach this problem would be appreciated if one of the above or something completely different.

**Notes**

I understand that this is not the suggested pattern for multiple contexts in breeze as the suggested pattern connects the sandbox to the persistent store then updates the master. However this mechanism doesn't appear the best option in my case as I would have to combine using the export data functionality for offline handling plus the connection found functionality needed in my master context.

The resultant problem for linking this question to an error (when continued from the example above) the user saves their sandbox (exports back to master) if the master has managed to save to persist store there are now 2 entities in the master context representing the same customer. These are customer -2 and customer 34. As a result of navigation properties this results in an:

> optimistic concurrency exception

from EF when mastercontext.saveChanges() is called.

Comment: The Question [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19667001/sync-breezejs-managers-broadcast-breezejs-changes) appears to be very similar.